# How to select more than one column using Regex

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame that has two columns with mostly numerical values, but also some values which are recorded as `>` or `<` eg `>10000` etc.

I need to filter the data so that it can be evaluated and the following works fine when these values are only in one column.

```
x_clean = x[!grepl('[^0-9]', x[[2]]),]
```

I first thought all these occurrences would involve both columns and only needed to use `col2`, but have found that sometime I get a numerical value in `col2` but a `</>` in `col3`

Using the following leaves me with a completely blank data frame.

```
x_clean = x[!grepl('[^0-9]', x[2:3]),]
```

I presume this because `[[]]` converts the col into a list and then `grepl` is not satisfied.

I would be grateful if someone can provide some assistance. Currently I repeat the evaluation a second time replacing the `2` with a `3`. This works fine, but seems very clumsy.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(head(x, 10))`

Comment: `x[2:3]` is a data.frame, while `x[[2]]` is a vector, not a list, fyi. It's not clear what you want to do by `!grepl`-ing with two cols at once. Is it a "neither of these" or "not both of these"?

Comment: Thanks Frank. I need remove non-numeric values from both col 2 and 3.

Comment: dmiris, the output is too large to post in the comment box. Is there a way to attach it. Please advise and I will post

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
grepl('[^0-9]', x[[2]]) & grepl('[^0-9]', x[[3]])
```

because grep only returns the evaulation of the regular expression 
for the first value from each field in the data.frame, see:

```
x = data.frame(a = c(1,2,'>3'),b=c(1,'<2',3),c = c(1,'<2','>3'))
x
#>    a  b  c
#> 1  1  1  1
#> 2  2 <2 <2
#> 3 >3  3 >3

grepl('[^0-9]', x[2:3])
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
```

or if you want to have to write different code when you want to 
condition on rows using grepl you can do someting like this:

```
temp <- lapply(x, function(x)grepl('[^0-9]',x))

temp
#> $a
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# applies the or operator (|) across all the arguments
OR <- function (...) 
{
    argList <- list(...)
    names(argList) <- NULL
    switch(as.character(length(argList)),
           `0` = NULL, 
           `1` = argList[[1]], 
           `2` = argList[[1]] | argList[[2]],
           do.call("OR", c(list(argList[[1]] | argList[[2]]), 
                            argList[-(1:2)])))
}

x_clean  <-  x[!do.call(OR,temp),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just convert to numeric; any entries that cannot be converted will become `NA` and can be filtered out. Besides, you'll want the data in numeric format if you're doing any subsequent analysis.

```
x[] <- lapply(x,function(x)as.numeric(as.character(x)))
na.omit(x)
```

Example:

```
x <- data.frame(x1=c(1,">1",2),x2=c(">1",2,3))
#   x1 x2
# 1  1 >1
# 2 >1  2
# 3  2  3

x[] <- lapply(x,function(x)as.numeric(as.character(x)))
na.omit(x)
#   x1 x2
# 3  2  3
```